# GNU parallel changes PATH environment variable

Tags: parallel-processing, environment-variables, gnu, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use GNU Parallel in order to run a script with several parameters on a remote machines.
This looks somewhat like:

```
parallel --onall -S remote-machine  /shared/location/script.sh ::: param_a param_b
```

`/shared/location/script.sh` is using git. So I get this error:

```
git: command not found
```

If I log in to `remote-machine` manually and run `/shared/location/script.sh` with `param_a` or `param_b` everything works fine. So I checked the $PATH variable and found out that if I run something on `remote-machine` using GNU parallel, it looks like `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. If I run it directly from the machine it has also `/local/bin/git`.

Why is it that way and how to overcome?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU Parallel uses ssh for remote execution, so the $PATH is the same as you would see when you run a non-interactive ssh session:

```
ssh server echo '$PATH'
parallel -S server --onall {} '$PATH' ::: echo
```

The reason you see a different $PATH when you log in is that interactive sessions may set another $PATH.

You can force `parallel` to copy an environment variable using --env:

```
parallel --env PATH -S server --onall {} '$PATH' ::: echo
```

Comment: You might also find `--wd .` useful to arrange for `parallel` to `cd` to the same directory on the ssh host.